# When I click the update button, it won't change/update (CodeIgniter, Update Multiple Rows)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
function update_agenda() {

    $id = $this->input->post['did'];
    $this->load->model('agenda_model');
    $data = array(
                      'nama' => $this->input->post('did'),
                      'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer')
                  );
    ($this->agenda_model->update($id, $data))
}
```

When I click button *Save*, it won't change anything. How can I fix this problem?

```html
        <td>
            <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" class=checkbox1 name="checklist" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>> <?php echo $agenda->id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="hide" name="did" value="<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>" disabled>
        </td>
         <?php }?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <button onclick="saveUpdate()"> Save </button>
```

This is my model:

```
function update ($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('agenda', $data);
}
```

[Here is my saveUpdate function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxgOg.png)

Comment: can you share you full code i mean controller,model, view ??

Comment: where is your model code ??

Comment: here i can`t identify bugs can you share your team viewer details or skype details ?

Comment: bro may be your id is coming wrong that`s why it`s not updating your data

Comment: oops, i changed 'nama' => $this->input->post('did'), into ..... ('dname'). It doesnt work

Comment: actually I also feel this error is because id is wrong , but I think I 've given the correct id value . any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this helpyou

view.php

```
        <td>
            <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" class=checkbox1 name="checklist" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>> <?php echo $agenda->id; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="hide" name="did" value="<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>" disabled>
        </td>
         <?php }?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <button onclick="saveUpdate()"> Save </button>
```

controller.php

```
function update_agenda() {
    $this->load->model('agenda_model');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('did', 'Did', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dketer', 'Dketer', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

     if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
    else{
        $id = $this->input->post['did'];

        $data = array(
                      'nama'       => $this->input->post('did'),
                      'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer')
                  );

        $this->agenda_model->update($id, $data);

        $data['agenda']   = $this->agenda_model->get_data($id);

        $this->load->view('formsuccess', $data);
    }
}
```

model.php

```
function update($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table', $data);
}

function get_data($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->get('table')->row();
}
```